# Escaping the special char in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am having a JSON object where I have to maintain list of timestamp

```
"interval": {
    "firstInterval": "5 * 60 * 1000", //5min
    "secondInterval": "30 * 60 * 1000" //30min
  }
```

When I try to access this value it changes to 5 milliseconds instead of 5min

```
var result= interval.firstInterval;
console.log(result) // Must be 5 min but changes to 5 milliseconds
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here. You are storing *string values* in your object. `interval.firstInterval` should yield the value `"5 * 60 * 1000"`.

Comment: You can use eval, like this eval(result)

Comment: Please don't use eval... `interval.firstInterval.match(/\d+/g).reduce(function (a, b) {return a * b});`.

Comment: Why are you storing arithmetic formulas as strings?

Comment: @torazaburo then is there any way to store in JSON?

Comment: Yes, store it as the number 300000.